# Virtualization and SCSI passthrough

Tags: virtual-machine, scanner, scsi

Is there a way to do SCSI passthrough in a virtualized environnement under Linux (Linux being the host OS, and MacOSX being the guest OS)?

My goal is to drive a high end scanner for which no driver exists for Linux. I currently have to a MacPro G5 but would like to get rid of the Mac hardware for room and convenience issues.

I looks like qemu/kvm can do it but only for storage type devices.

Would the solution be a Xen hypervisor?

Comment: You might be able to pass the SCSI controller through to the VM...